# How to close stdout/stderr window in python?

Tags: python, printing, window

In my python app, I print some stuff during a cycle.

After the cycle, I want to close the `stdout/stderr` window that the prints produced using python code.

Comment: It isn't "a stdout/stderr window"; that terminology is nonsense. It's like saying "a Ford/Chrysler highway". It's a *terminal* window, that the Python process's stdout and stderr are dumped into.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: "close the stdout/stderr streams written by the process"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import sys

sys.stdout.close()
sys.stderr.close()
```

Might be what you want.  This will certainly close stdout/stderr at any rate.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the prompt window that opens when you run a Python script on MS Windows, try specifying the executable `pythonw` instead of `python`, on the first line of your script.